# TasksBoard on Safari does not sync

Tags: google-calendar, google-tasks, safari, tasksboard

My TasksBoard is not syncing with my Google Calendar and my TasksBoard app (using Safari). It shows a loading indicator at the top screen, and when I try to refresh it raises the above quote:

> Some tasks are still queued to sync. Please wait for the sync to complete.

[image: Taskboard showing loading indicator]

I don't want to refresh the page completely since I'm afraid that I will undo all changes.

What should I do? Why does it happening?

Comment: TasksBoard is not an app from Google. Please add the name and version of the operative system and version of Safari. Also try to find the supported browser / system requirements and follow the guidance from https://tasksboard.com/troubleshoot

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue solved

Rendering the page didn't undo changes but did not help with syncing.

I solved this issue by opening the TaskBoard on Chrome on the same computer (instead of Safari), the data was already up to date, and it synced immediately.

### TL;DR

Sync your data using Chrome, it seems that there is an issue with the Safari version.